# Clover Code Coverage: Instrumenting Unit Tests

Tags: maven, unit-testing, clover

I'm using Clover for code coverage and I have the following setup in my pom.xml file.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
                <generateXml>false</generateXml>
                <includesTestSourceRoots>false</includesTestSourceRoots>
                <includesAllSourceRoots>true</includesAllSourceRoots>
                <license>MyLicense</license>
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/classes/</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/generated-sources/</exclude>                  
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>main</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                        <goal>log</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>site</id>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>clover</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then I run Maven the following way:

```
mvn clean install  clover2:instrument clover2:instrument-test   clover2:aggregate clover2:clover
```

Though I see code coverage and other details, I see the following warning:

**No test results
No test results could be found. Please ensure that you have instrumented your unit tests correctly.**

What does this mean? How do I instrument Junit test case classes for Clover?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.
I had to set the following value to "true":

```
<includesTestSourceRoots>true</includesTestSourceRoots>
```